# Virtualbox Guests crashing during boot

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, virtualhost

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 and for some reason Virtualbox Guests are crashing in the early stages of starting up.

This has happened on a variety of Linux distros I have tried to start.

Here is the log file for an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine.

http://pastebin.com/nJ0FhBpC

Not sure what I have screwed up here as I have set up Virtualbox a few times now and have never had such an issue exist.

Comment: I have the same issue after I upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 today. The upgrade contained `virtualbox:amd64 (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5, 4.3.34-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1)`. I will try to down-grade.

Comment: I have the same issue after I upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 today. The upgrade updated Virtualbox from `4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5` to `4.3.34-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1`.  More info at http://askubuntu.com/q/702563/425630

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from Virtualbox 4.3.10 to Virtualbox 4.3.34 breaks USB.

Upgrading the extension pack will solve your issue.

For details, see [update to virtualbox 4.3.34 causing issues on ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/702638/425630)